# Error while archive in xCode using react native. Can you tell me what issue?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

Error details below:

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_RCTWebSocketModule in:
        /Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NetAgentApp-fuhngzgxmwbkcrgizkhvwsoqfslw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/NetAgentApp/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libReact.a(RCTWebSocketModule.o)
        /Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NetAgentApp-fuhngzgxmwbkcrgizkhvwsoqfslw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/NetAgentApp/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libRCTWebSocket.a(RCTWebSocketModule.o)
    ld: 459 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

[image: Linked Binary with library]

Answer (score 0):

This error caused by linking binary with libraries. Please check your linked libraries.

Comment: Actually it build and run properly but could not archive. We already checked linked libraries but couldn't find exactly.

Comment: I also add screen shots of linked binary with library.

Comment: Your libAirMaps.a is not linked properly. Try removing it and add again.